# Normality testing ToothGrowth

Tags: normal-distribution

I would like to ask opinion on normality testing. I will be using ToothGrowth data set.

I would like to perform t-test looking for difference of tooth growth between OJ and VC groups

```
data= Toothgrowth
```

[image: boxplot of toothgrowth]

should I test normality for the tooth growth separately?

```
OJ <- subset(data[data$supp== "OJ",])
VC <- subset(data[data$supp== "VC",])

shapiro.test(OJ$len)
shapiro.test(VC$len)

 OJ <- subset(data[data$supp== "OJ",])
 VC <- subset(data[data$supp== "VC",])
 shapiro.test(OJ$len)
```

gives me

```
    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  OJ$len
W = 0.91784, p-value = 0.02359
```

while

```
 shapiro.test(VC$len)
```

gives me

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  VC$len
W = 0.96567, p-value = 0.4284
```

or should I do it combined?

```
boxplot(data$len)
shapiro.test(data$len)
 boxplot(data$len)
 shapiro.test(data$len)
```

which gives me

```
    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  data$len
W = 0.96743, p-value = 0.1091
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which question are you trying to answer.

If you are trying to investigate if each population is a normal distribution, we test them separately.

If you are trying to investigate if the combined population is a normal distribution, we test them together. Remark: You might also want to consider if the sample proportion is reflective of the population proportion as you do so.